# I want to check parameters before puting them into constructor

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance

In class b I want to check if n and m are bigger than 0 and then put them into the constructor of a. How can I do it?

```
class a{
private:
    int x; int y;
public:
    a(int x, int y){
        this->x=x; this->y=y;
    }
    void print(){
        cout<<x<<" "<<y<<endl;
    }
};

class b:public a{
public:
    b(int n,int m):a(){
        ///
    }
};
```

Comment: What should happen if `n` and/or `m` are NOT bigger than 0? Do you want to pass 0s to `a()`, or do you want the code to fail?

Comment: i just want to understand how can i use if/else statement before i put into the notbase class constructor...

Comment: You can't use `if/else` like that. But you can write a function that is called while preparing to pass values to the base constructor, eg: `int verify(int n, int m, int result) { return ((n > 0) && (m > 0)) ? result : 0; } ... b(int n, int m) : a(verify(n, m, n), verify(n , m, m)) {}`

Comment: What you can do in a constructor's initialization list is very limited. If you need to do complex things, do them inside the constructor body instead. Change `x` and `y` to `protected`, initialize `a` using defaults, and let `b()` override `x` and `y` as needed after `a` is initialized.

Comment: okay i think it's a best way to use function to check variable as you want and than put it in to the constructor. But what you mean initialize a using default and let b()  override i ?dont understand.

Comment: `b(int n, int m) : a() { if ((n > 0) && (m > 0)) { x = n; y = m; } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a more elegant approach to this, but this is the best I've got right now. You can use the [ternary operator](http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/operators/ternary-operator.html) to check the variables as they are being passed into the call to `a`'s constructor.

```
#include <iostream>

class a
{
private:
    int x; int y;
public:
    a(int x = 0, int y = 0)
    {
        this->x = x; this->y = y;
    }

    void print()
    {
        std::cout << x << " " << y << "\n";
    }
};

class b : public a
{
public:
    b(int n,int m) : a( 
        n > 0 && m > 0 ? n : 0, 
        n > 0 && m > 0 ? m : 0
    )
    {

    }
};

int main()
{
  b B(-1, 1);
  B.print();

  b B2(1, 1);
  B2.print();

  b B3(-1, -1);
  B3.print();
}
```

The output is:

```
0 0
1 1
0 0
```

This approach might be frowned upon depending on your standard for code style, and doesn't take advantage of your default values in `a`'s constructor, but it will get the job done, at least in this simple example.

Comment: Downvoter: I get that this is a bit ugly, but a comment about why you don't like it and a better way to do it would be appreciated.

Comment: who said that i don't like it ? it was very smart

Comment: @MateGvenetadze someone downvoted it, it has +2/-1 right now.  I only want feedback from whoever did it.